# How do I enable Python last command history in Git Bash for Windows?

Tags: python, git-bash

The last Python command entered and executed in the Python interpreter can be recalled by pressing the up arrow.

This works as expected in the Windows CMD and Powershell, but in Git Bash for Windows **the up arrow has no effect**.

Alternatively, if I try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> I get:

```
user@DESKTOP MINGW64 ~
$ python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 1
>>> ^P^P
```

Similarly, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> as suggested in another answer just produces a `p` on the command input.

How can we enable Python command history for Git Bash?

Comment: Try to press Control+P combined , what happens ? does it bring The last Python command entered and executed in the Python interpreter ?

Comment: No, sadly it brings up " ^P ". I updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `.pythonstartup` file add this line or create it if it doesn't exist:

```py
import readline
```

Be sure to add the full path of the `.pythonstartup` file as an environment variable named `PYTHONSTARTUP`

That should fix it. If you get an import error, install it like so:

```sh
pip install pyreadline
```

Or, if you are using Anaconda, use:

```sh
conda install pyreadline
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Since this question is about Windows specifically and I ran into this problem with my data scientist hat on I added some more specifics.

Comment: A problem I've been researching for months. This answer never came up re: `command line up arrow not working` searches.  With git bash at least, this is the only solution I've found that works.

Answer (score 3):

`pyreadline` is not maintained anymore. Install [pyreadline3](https://github.com/pyreadline3/pyreadline3) instead, and you don't need to bother with setting environment variables and startup files.

```
pip install pyreadline3
```

Source: https://bugs.python.org/issue45870 (last message)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.